# How to Bind ICollection with EntityFramework 4.1 with DBContext Generator

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I would like to know how to use simple databinding (grid.datasource = xxxx) 
with DBContext Generator and entity framework 4.1;

With POCO entity Generator, i was able to do

```
Grid.DataSource = Entity.MyChildreCollection;
```

(probably because Poco entity generator use FixUp Collection)

But with DBContext Generator this property is ICollection so can't be bind directly .

What's the best practise to bind my entity collection to a grid ?

I've try changing T4 template from `HashSet<T>`  to

```
 ObservableListSource<T> 
(with ObservableListSource<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, IListSource)
```

I've noticed that if i do that, 
i can't use

```
Item.Collection.Remove(CollectionItem);
```

because it doesn't delete the association

but i can do that

```
Contexte.CollectionSet.Remove(CollectionItem);
```

i don't have this problem with ICollection ... what is the difference ?

Moreover changing ICollection to ObservableListSource can make trouble to serialize the entities ...

What are the best way to doing that ?

Thanks